# Is it possible to modify experiment parameter values after a model is run?

Tags: java, anylogic

I'm following the [Integrating AnyLogic Models with External Java Applications](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fcode%2Fintegration.html) module and while I am able to change parameters before I run the exported java application, it seems the values become immutable once the model runs. Is there a way to dynamically modify parameter values at runtime?

Below is a snippet of my Java code:

```
    final Simulation s = new Simulation();
    IExperimentHost host = new ExperimentHost(s);
    s.parameter1 = 50;
    s.setup(host);
    host.launch();
    s.runTheModel();
    s.parameter1 = 100;
```

The result is that parameter1 never changes from 50 to 100. Is there a way to circumvent this?

Answer (score 0):

Try set_parameter. The help menu talks about this a little bit.

Edit:
Your original question was not directly linked to running as an external java application, but I think this could really simplify things.  When you export your java application, look at the .bat file.  You will see what the command line would look like to run the model.  What we do when we are running from an external application is just have the external application call this command line, as opposed to what AnyLogic discusses in the help menu. A significant advantage of this is that you can easily mimic in the development environment what is going on in the exported model.

Ask your self why you are changing these parameters at runtime.  Is it because of a read statement and you just don't have the data prior to the model run?  If so, think about the order you instantiate your objects and don't start them until after you have the variables set that you want to use.  This can be done by passing in parameters to main, setting database values, or having the main agent do various read statements.

Is it that you just want items to change over time?  If so, consider variables, instead of parameters.  Consider other objects that may allow you to more easily change flow.  For example, does a valve before a pipeline or other sequence give you the level of control that you want?

At this point, would probably need more detailed information about what you are trying to accomplish / the system you are modeling, in order to provide any more specific advice.

Comment: I tried that but it seems set_parameter1 is unrecognized: "The method set_inflowPar1(int) is undefined for the type Simulation." For clarity, I am running this model in an external java environment as a standalone java application. I am able to access s.inflowPar1 but not s.set_inflowPar1().

Comment: Re-read your original post in more detail.  I am editing the answer to expand on running from the command line a little more & other general items.  We use set_parameter at the main (or other agent) level after the model has started running.  It may not be possible to use it at the experiment level, which is what "s" is.  Or, it may be that you change it at the experiment level, but it just doesn't propagate down, based on where/how you are using it.

Comment: It could be that some parameters cannot be changed in the fluid library after start.  I know this was the case a few years ago when the fluid library was brand new.  We used other components to manage flow as desired.

Comment: Thank you for the edit! I am indeed trying to change items over time; we are trying to make an API so as to allow these items to be modified remotely at runtime, thus why we are using a standalone Java app. We have exposed variables, but I am having issues accessing the variables in my Java code, as detailed in the post. If it is of any help, our simple model is accessible through: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zf30b9n67rrucew/Simplified_launch3.alp?dl=0

Comment: I realize now that I have been using parameters and variables almost interchangeably. I want to clarify that we are indeed using variables so as to change them at runtime.